# How can I detect keyboard events in Gmail

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, gmail, dom-events

I am writing a browser extension that needs to attach handlers to the `keyup` and `keydown` events on all pages. I can get it working pretty well with the following content script code.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown",keyDown, true);      
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUp, true);
```

I can't get this to work in Gmail though. Specifically I can't get it to work when composing the body of an new email. It will work everywhere else I have tested. I think the problem is because Gmail is calling `stopPropagation` on all keyboard events but it is difficult to debug their minimized code. I thought that setting the 3rd parameter to `true` would cause the event to be captured during the `CAPTURE_PHASE` but this isn't working.

How can I capture `keyup` and `keydown` events while composing a new body in Gmail with a Google Chrome content script?

Edit:

I've ensured that my content scripts are being injected into all iframes of the DOM by adding `"all_frames": true,` to my manifest. I have even tried using the following code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function (event) {
     if(event.type === "DOMNodeInserted") {
        if(event.srcElement.nodeName === "IFRAME") {
        console.log(event.srcElement.nodeName + " iframe detected");
        event.srcElement.addEventListener("keydown", function(kevent) {
            document.dispatchEvent(kevent);
            }, true);
        event.srcElement.addEventListener("keyup", function(kevent) {
            document.dispatchEvent(kevent);
            }, true);
        
    }
}
},true);
```

This still doesn't fix the issue with Gmail.

Comment: Gmail also tends to have a lot of iframes. Make sure you are listening for events in the correct ones.

Comment: I've ensured that my content scripts are being injected into all iframes. I've even tried one build where I detected when iframes are added to the DOM like so: (see edit)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because `event.srcElement` refers to the `<iframe>` element, not its content. To access its content document, you have to wait for the frame to be loaded (`onload` or polling), then use `frame.contentDocument` to access the frame.

Starting from Chrome 37.0.1995.0, you can also use the [`match_about_blank`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#match_about_blank) (with [all_frames](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#all_frames)) to insert a content script in the `about:blank` frame that captures the event and sends it to the parent content script.

Here is an example of an implementation for the original idea (using polling):

The relevant parts of `manifest.json`:

```
  "content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["*://mail.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["contentscript.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
  }],
```

`contentscript.js`

```
function keyDown(e) {console.log(e.which);}; // Test
function keyUp(e) {console.log(e.keyCode);}; // Test
(function checkForNewIframe(doc) {
    if (!doc) return; // document does not exist. Cya

    // Note: It is important to use "true", to bind events to the capturing
    // phase. If omitted or set to false, the event listener will be bound
    // to the bubbling phase, where the event is not visible any more when
    // Gmail calls event.stopPropagation().
    // Calling addEventListener with the same arguments multiple times bind
    // the listener only once, so we don't have to set a guard for that.
    doc.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown, true);
    doc.addEventListener('keyup', keyUp, true);
    doc.hasSeenDocument = true;
    for (var i = 0, contentDocument; i<frames.length; i++) {
        try {
            contentDocument = iframes[i].document;
        } catch (e) {
            continue; // Same-origin policy violation?
        }
        if (contentDocument && !contentDocument.hasSeenDocument) {
            // Add poller to the new iframe
            checkForNewIframe(iframes[i].contentDocument);
        }
    }
    setTimeout(checkForNewIframe, 250, doc; // <-- delay of 1/4 second
})(document); // Initiate recursive function for the document.
```

Note that I used polling instead of DOM mutation events, because the latter **[heavily reduces performance](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.platform/browse_thread/thread/2f42f1d75bb906fb?pli=1)**.

Comment: I've made a separate test extension with this code and it will not work while typing in the body of a gmail email document.

Comment: @ZeroDivide The Gmail's email body is a frame inside a frame. I have updated my answer with a recursive, non-conflicting function to add events.

Comment: The code works pretty well, the only problem I have noticed is that it never reaches a base case and keeps looking for iFrames. I'm not sure if this will be a problem or not? Should I try to make it quit polling after a few seconds?

Comment: I also wanted to know what the numbers after the `doc.rwEventsAdded9424550` are?

Comment: This seems to work fine when using these event handlers. When I use this function in my original extension, it throws off my timing measurements that are made using global variables. I'm not sure what to do with it now. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @ZeroDivide I added this long-term polling to account for elements which are added later. When you create a new message, a new iframe is created. Using `DOMNodeInserted` to detect this dramatically decreases performance. Polling is a better solution. Increase the delay if it's not *that* important to immediately have a listener for the new iframe. I added these numbers to make sure that the variable is not used. I used `rw`, because that's how I prefix my own custom variables. These numbers equal the postId of your question. Combined together, I have got a pretty unique descriptive variable.

Comment: Update: I will check the example from Rob W. this is probably due to the sandbox .. - This looks great, but I get "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL ... Domains, protocols and ports must match." Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Can you find any frame which is not hosted on the `//mail.google.com` protocol + domain? (are you actually trying this on GMail?). If you think that the problem is more complex, consider creating a new question. The comments should not be used to ask follow-up questions.

Comment: @RobW Ok thx, I found a plus.google fram. Posted the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569723/chrome-extension-unsafe-javascript-attempt-to-access-frame-with-url-domains-pr

Comment: This works well. but throws errors on accessing embedded iframes in a different document domain than the containing page. (even though the code is in an extension with permission on both pages) Any idea how to fix this? -- "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL (foo) from frame with URL (bar)"

Comment: @DavidJeske Please take the time to read the three comments before your comment (here's a link to make it more obvious: **SO Q&A: "[Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL https://plus.google.com/u/0/_/...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569723/chrome-extension-unsafe-javascript-attempt-to-access-frame-with-url-domains-pr)"**).

Comment: @RobW the keypress capturing phase argument was the kicker for me. With that set correctly, the keypress event fires for keys in the gmail compose window without having to use all_frames=true or loop through all iframe documents.

Answer (score -1):

This might help

[how can I listen for keyboard events in gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51014426/how-can-i-listen-for-keyboard-events-in-gmail)

> DOM bubbling starts on window so you need to attach your listeners there and specify 3rd parameter true to indicate the capturing phase, which is actually the first event phase. –
> wOxxOm

based on your code, it could be like this:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown",keyDown, true);      
window.addEventListener("keyup", keyUp, true);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).