# jQuery effect selector now and in the future WITHOUT an event

Tags: jquery

Here is an example usage, of what I am trying to do:

```
  $('img.switchToPng').each(function(){
       currentSRC = $(this).attr('src');
       $(this).attr('src', currentSRC.substr(0, currentSRC.length -3) + 'png');
  });
```

Later using ajax a new `<img src="path/image.jpg" alt="blah" class="switchToPng" />` appears in the dom, I would like that to NOT require rerunning the selector and each function. With `.on` selectors in jQuery can live into the future, however I cannot find a way to use it without an event. I could use a `'load'` event, but that would not be reliable as browser cache may prevent that from firing.

If this is possible, I can see many uses. Does anyone know a good answer to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three options:

1. Polling for the creation of new elements. <sup>[[Example]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424550/how-can-i-detect-keyboard-events-in-gmail/9439525#9439525)</sup>
2. Modifying the (jQuery) methods which insert the new element:

   ```
   var originalAppend = jQuery.fn.append;
   jQuery.fn.append = function() {
       // Function logic...
       return originalAppend.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
   };
   ```
3. Using deprecated [DOM mutation](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.platform/browse_thread/thread/2f42f1d75bb906fb?pli=1) methods.

Comment: Can you explain or link me to more information on 1. ? I have not encountered that concept.

Comment: @Fresheyeball I have linked an example, with annotated code. Summary: Keep a poller (using `setTimeout` or `setInterval`) running, which checks for the existence of elements which match a certain selector. When such an element is found, apply some one-time function logic to it, and attach an identifier/flag/(data-)attribute to mark it as "touched". At later calls, ignore elements which have this propery/flag set. Since this is run periodically, **avoid** expensive jQuery where possible, and use vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: Polling sounds really heavy. The kind of thing that makes me wish javascript had threads. Is there a vanilla javascript technique you can recommend? I started with jQuery and am only now getting deeper into true javascript.

Comment: @Fresheyeball I have linked an example, try to create an own implementation for learning purposes ;) Once it's finished, or when you're running in trouble, don't hesitate asking for help.