# Chrome Extension: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL Domains, protocols and ports must match

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, gmail

This answer specifies explains how to access the content of all iframes on gmail.com https://stackoverflow.com/a/9439525/222236

But on mail.google.com it throws this error:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL https://plus.google.com/u/0/_/... from frame with URL https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

I tried adding `*://plus.google.com/*` to the matches of the manifest of the extension, but it didn't help.

Update: Checking for the url before accessing the content works, but my logic is very crude at the moment as it only checks for google plus:

```
        if(-1==iframes[i].src.indexOf('plus.google.com')) {
            contentDocument = iframes[i].contentDocument;
            if (contentDocument && !contentDocument.rweventsadded73212312) {
                // add poller to the new iframe
                checkForNewIframe(iframes[i].contentDocument);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I believe that in many cases it can be a requirement to traverse all subframes, and exclusion of external domains from control flow would break application's main function. So, in the case of chrome extension I suggest to replace the loop through frames with _content_scripts_ `"all_frames": true` declaration in the manifest, and optional logic to merge the results (if necessary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access is blocked due to the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).
The right way to avoid the error is to exclude the frames from a different origin. Your logic is very crude indeed. It does not specifically look in the host name, and it doesn't account for other domains.
Invert the logic to have a robust solution:

```
if (iframes[i].src.indexOf(location.protocol + '//' + location.host) == 0 ||
    iframes[i].src.indexOf('about:blank') == 0 || iframes[i].src == '') {
```

Explanation of this *white list*:

- `protocol://host/` = `https://mail.google.com`.
  Obviously, the current host has to be allowed
- `about:blank` and an empty string
  These frames are dynamically created and scripted by GMail.

Answer (score 1):

`mail.google.com` and `plus.google.com` are not the same domain. JavaScript implementations in modern web browsers do not allow cross-domain scripting.

Without resorting to different kinds of hackery, the correct way to get around this is through CORS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), which is not available to you in this circumstance.