# accessing https iframe element on chrome-extension

Tags: google-chrome, https, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I added an iframe and jquery to my popup.html.

```
<iframe id="xyz" border="0" src="https://xyz.com/test"></iframe>
```

and trying to reach an element of this iframe with this command via console :

```
$("#xyz").contents().find("body").fadeIn();
```

but it giving this error :

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL https://xyz.com/test from frame with URL chrome-extension://my-extension-id/popup.html. The frame requesting access has a protocol of 'chrome-extension', **the frame being accessed has a protocol of 'https'. Protocols must match**
```

**I searched google for this error but there is no error like this. All of them saying domain must match etc. But this one saying only protocols must match. How can I solve this protocols problem?**

And I have this line on my manifest file.

```
"permissions": [
    "*://xyz.com/*"
]
```

Comment: Could you possibly `fadein` the frame itself instead of its content?

Comment: @Stan Frame is already fadein. But body, which one is in iframe, has "style='visibility: hidden'" property, so it's not appearing when you load the iframe :)

Comment: Ok, then just inject your content script into the frame, and run in its context.

Comment: Agree with @Stan. Inject in a content script, and then when the content script runs, use chrome.extension.sendMessage to pass the information back to the background page.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an issue with [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Try following the solution mentioned in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11576355/924643). Also, try doing it through native Javascript first before trying to do it using jQuery.

Comment: The first line is true, the suggested solution is not. The problems of the questions are different: In your suggested solution, the problem was an unwanted error caused by unwanted access to a frame. The problem in this question is that the frame cannot be accessed due to the Same origin policy.

Comment: But I already did the permission thing about origin policy : http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html

Comment: @xecute That is cross origin **XMLHttpRequest**. That is different from cross-origin **frame access**. Out-of-the-box cross-origin frame access is not possible. You need to use content scripts and/or `postMessage` to do this programatically (I've already posted many answers, so I won't repeat that again). Another way (*not* recommended) is to disable the same-origin policy using the `--disable-web-security` flag.