# Chrome extension - doeesn't work in Gmail

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, gmail, keydown

#### What does the extension do?

Whenever there is a `keydown` event on `textarea`, my extension's `detector.js` content script calls a function and manipulates the values of the textarea.
Since Gmail does not use `<textarea>` in "Compose Mail", but instead a `div` with `role='textbox'`, I tried to catch it using:

```
console.log("---------------------------------");

var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var temp = [];

for(var i = 0, len = div.length; i < len; i++){
    var node = div[i];
    if(node.hasAttribute("role")){
        if(node.getAttribute("role") === "textbox"){
            temp.push(node);
        }
    }
}

div = temp.slice(0);

var textarea = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");  // for the normal textboxes

// Log to console the <#NodeList>s
console.log(div);
console.log(textarea);

// Attach the event listeners
for(var i = 0, len = div.length; i < len; i++){
    div[i].addEventListener("keydown", keyDown, false);
}

for(var i = 0, len = textarea.length; i < len; i++){
    textarea[i].addEventListener("keydown", keyDown, false);
}

function keyDown(e){
    // some code....
}
```

#### What's the problem then

On a normal page like StackOverflow, I get output similar to:

```
====================================================== 
Array[0]
NodeList[2]
```

What I get on Gmail:

```
// Nothing, no logs, no errors, not even the `----` line :(
```

#### What I tried:

Everything, checked all the similar questions here, and did lots of `console.log`s, but of course none worked.

#### Limitations:

I don't want to use jQuery or similar plug-ins, just good old vanilla JS.

#### More links:

[Here is my manifest.json](http://hastebin.com/vewirixide.dos)

Please help.

Comment: Gmail tends to use a number of iframes. Try adding `"all_frames": true` to the [content script object](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) of your manifest.

Comment: @abraham No luck :( Thanks though.

Comment: Updated manifest.json link.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on "compose mail" button, gmail opens a new IFrame.
You have to add a listener for your DOM to check for new IFrames on it.
Check out this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424550/how-can-i-detect-keyboard-events-in-gmail)